# Rest api return list of images with Node JS to Android user

Tags: android, c++, node.js

Good evening,

I seek how to retrieve the result of a c ++ file (main.cpp) then I send it to an android user, I'm talking about JSON (REST).
that is to say, after storing the image on the server (sent by the user) I have to run the main.cpp file and I get the result (of the image sets) and then I send it to user (android application).

so I tried to store the image on my server through this code (works):

```
pp.post('/up', function(req, res) {
var pathimg;
req.pipe(req.busboy); 
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
pathimg = fs.createWriteStream('/home/usr1/Public/server/files/' + filename); 
file.pipe(pathimg);             
fs.readFile('/home/usr1/Public/server/files/'' + filename, unction read(err, data) 
{      
if(err){
res.json({'response':"Error upload"});     
}else
{
res.json({'response':"Saved to server :)"});
}       
});
};
```

I tried running the main.cpp and recovers its result:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = './test';
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
// La résultat est dans stdout 
console.log('stdout  ->>: '+stdout);
console.log('stderr: '+stderr);
if(error !== null){
console.log('Ops Problem of exec : ' +error);             
}
});
```

but this code executes the file without retrieving the results in a JSON object

Comment: `the result of a c ++ file` ???? What should that be?

Comment: The project idea is the recognition of items in an image (SIFT and SURF) so I used the OpenCV library in C ++ with Qt Creator,
this is the result of the program (main.cpp) is the framing of the object as it shows the image below, it is returning a list of images that contains the old image (not yet): http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/9593287801.png

Comment: then I seek to store the results of the program (main.cpp) in a file for read and send to user (android application) in a JSON object because I use a REST web service with Node.js

if you have other solution does not hesitate to help me and thank you